# File Transfer Button in Live Agent Not Working

Tags: liveagent, files, support

We've suddenly started to see an issue in Live Agent where, if an agent requests a File Transfer, the button presented to the user to upload the file does nothing when clicked. It'll get the focus state styling (attached image for reference), but never actually present them with a way to upload. Anyone ran into something like this before?

[image]

Update: I discovered that it does work as expected in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue created for this. Will be fixed soon: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001FSjaQAG